# Is there any IDA plugin to display AST?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, hexrays

Hex Ray has introduced a decompiler API as part of IDA v6.6. Is there any plugin which displays the detail Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) produced by the decompiler graphically?

I want something like [this](http://www.hexblog.com/decompilation/video/vd2.html) as mentioned in this [post](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=66). Unfortunately, I can't find the `Display graph` option in IDA v6.95

Comment: My browser doesn't like Flash :) Can you make a screenshot and include it in your post?

Answer (score 2):

See the `vds5` plugin in the Hex-Rays SDK.

```
/*
 *      Hex-Rays Decompiler project
 *      Copyright (c) 2007-2008 by Hex-Rays, support@hex-rays.com
 *      ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
 *
 *      Sample plugin for the Hex-Rays Decompiler.
 *      It adds a new command to show graph of the ctree.
 *      The current item will be highlighted in the graph.
 *
 *      The command hotkey is G. It is also added into the right-click menu.
 *
 *      To display the graph, we traverse the ctree and build
 *      a gdl_graph_t object. Then we use gen_gdl() function from IDA
 *      to create a GDL file from this object. Finally, we call
 *      wingraph32 to display the graph on the screen.
 *
 */
```

Comment: Python version of `vds5` is not available for IDA v6.95

https://github.com/idapython/src/tree/master/examples

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock and your point is?

Comment: Since I am using IDA v6.95, I can't use `vds5` unfortunately. BTW, to use CPP version of the same, I need IDA SDK to compile it. Right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Hex-Rays SDK in 6.95 includes vds5 (native version). If not, you should contact support.

Comment: I just checked IDA SDK 6.95, couldn't find `vds5`. Where should it be located? I'll check one final time before reaching out support.

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/hexrays_sample5_8cpp-example.shtml

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: I have it in "plugins\hexrays_sdk\plugins\vds5"